# install_name_tool error when running virtualenv on Mac OSX Lion (with Xcode)

Tags: python, osx-lion, virtualenv, install-name-tool

When I try to run mkvirtualenv with python 2.6, I get the error:

Could not call install_name_tool -- you must have Apple's development tools installed

I've installed Xcode. (It's actually installed, not just downloaded and waiting to be installed).

The command: which install_name_tool yields me nothing. Why can't I call it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Xcode 4.3, you'll have to install the Command Line Tools package, available under the Downloads tab in the preferences.

Comment: Yes! That fixed the install_name_tool! Thank you!

I'm still getting this error though:
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
Look familiar?

Comment: wxf! I need a developer account to do that? that process takes N steps of bureaucracy... i just want to code! Anyone knows if its possible to install Command Line Tools without dev account and/or if on XCode 4.2 should work?

Comment: @Luchux: You can just get a free account.

Comment: i feel calm again :) I will figure it out how painful is the process. Thanks.

Comment: @Luchux: It's not painful -- you just sign up.